# Specify Path in Script Paramter in Scheduled task

Tags: powershell

if I create a scheduled task which starts a Powershell script like this:

```
Powershell -command "& 'C:\test.ps1'"
```

How can I put in a path argument in a parameter that doesn't interrupt the `-command` parameter?

```
Powershell -command "& 'C:\test.ps1 -path C:\Program Files(x86)\test'"
```

would not work because it could not find `"C:\Program"`

```
Powershell -command "& 'C:\test.ps1 -path 'C:\Program Files(x86)\test''"
or
Powershell -command "& 'C:\test.ps1 -path "C:\Program Files(x86)\test"'"
```

would not work because the quotes that wrap the path would interrupt the `-command` Parameter

Comment: you should specify `-file` and not `-command`

Comment: @Avshalom `-file "C:\script.ps1 -path 'C:\test'"` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-File` Parameter instead of the `-Command`

```
Powershell -File C:\script.ps1 -path C:\test
```